# How to have multiple remix routes serving the same file?

Tags: typescript, react-router, remix.run

Is it possible to do the following in Remix Run?

File system:
routes/house.tsx

Routes:

/house <- this maps to the file system perfectly

/houses

/housing

How can I make '/houses' and '/housing' also go to the routes/house.tsx file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Remix currently doesn’t support multiple routes to the same file. However you can create the routes you want and import from the original file.

```js
// housing.tsx
export * from ‘./house’
export { default } from ‘./house’
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is this in their documentation or just a workaround because of the lack of support for multiple routes serving the same file?

Comment: It seems to break the `meta` when accessing from the file that `export` (`housing.tsx` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Pathless Layout Routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.14.0/guides/routing#pathless-layout-routes)

So in your case, you could move `routes/house.tsx` to `routes/__house.tsx`, and create a folder `routes/__house/` with empty files for the routes you want to match:

```
routes/__house.tsx             <- original house.tsx
routes/__house/house.tsx       <- empty
routes/__house/housing.tsx     <- empty
routes/__house/houses.tsx      <- empty
```

Comment: This doesn't work